# Why won't some highlights finish saving?

Tags: technical-issues, overwatch

I like saving my highlights that I think are at least notable, if not pretty good or great.  However, on two instances so far, the progress bar for saving the highlight has completely stopped, and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do to recover.

I can hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> and click the cancel button, but that doesn't do anything; I'm still stuck on the screen with the progress bar.  No other key press does anything either.  I basically have to force quit out (<kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> works) and reload the game in order for me to do anything.

I've also tried lowering the settings of the recording, but that didn't do anything either.  It still gets stuck.

This issue shows consistent behaviour with particular highlights.  It always seems to happen, and it always stops recording in the same spot.  Just playing the highlight doesn't do anything unexpected, though; it plays start to finish just fine.

Why is Overwatch doing this, and how do I fix it?

---

Tonight is the third time this has happened, and I went even further reducing the quality of the video:

- 1080p (this is my normal setting)
- x1 super sample (usually x2)
- 30 fps (usually 60 fps)
- low movie quality (usually ultra)
- auto movie format (still happens if I select WebM explicitly)
- hardware encoding off (normally it's on)
- music on (not that it should matter in this case)

The only thing that seems to be common between the various highlights is that they tend to have a lot of particles/effects.

Comment: I've even gone so far as to set my game settings to low, hoping that might fix it, but alas, it seems to not have worked.

Comment: Might be worth including your computer specs (including HD and SSDs you may have with used space/total space)

Comment: I've got a Intel Core i5-4670, 16GB RAM, an NVidia GTX 970, and I'm recording to an almost empty 2TB hybrid hard drive.  I don't think it's a lack of appropriate hardware (although my GPU doesn't seem to have an H.264 hardware encoder).  Also, as I said, this is only an issue in a few highlights; most of the time, a given highlight will save just fine.

Comment: Hmm, and I am assuming you have done the standard first steps restart (obviously since this is a repeating problem), [scan and repair](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/7655), and then as a last resort uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: So uninstall and reinstall means I can't retest on a highlight that's known to fail, so it doesn't really help.  Scan and repair didn't find any issues, and although I haven't necessarily restarted my computer after a highlight failed to save, I do have to at least quit the game each time it happens.

Comment: My only other recommendation would be to try posting as a bug on the [official forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/22813881/). My friend was having some issues with Overwatch crashing/not working properly that were related to his specific graphics card (AMD). If your problem is hardware specific they might be able to help you on the forums

Comment: I haven't seen this happen in a while, so it may have been fixed in an update.

Comment: Had a look through past patch notes and saw nothing around that time. Possibly an aggressive Anti-Virus program? If you notice it again, open Task Manager and view the Performance tab (or resource monitor) on the disk you're trying to save to and see if it is actually saving.